# ClickOnce Deployment, remove fileGroup

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have .NET 4.0 application and I'm using ClickOnce deployment. I have few file groups which are downloaded dynamically in code:

```
ApplicationDeployment deploy = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
deploy.DownloadFileGroup(downloadGroupName);
```

Is there some way to uninstall this groups?

Comment: What did you mean by "uninstall the groups"? Do you want to remove these files from the client machine?

Comment: If I add some group to application, can I remove this group?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the files that belong to that group from disk and the
next time the application starts it will pick up on that.

Imagine you had a FileGroup called `"GROUPA"` which contains a single file `somefile.txt`.
You determine the location of the executing assembly and delete that file:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
    var deployment = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment;
    if (deployment.IsFileGroupDownloaded("GROUPA"))
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var fileToDelete = Path.Combine(path, "somefile.txt");
        File.Delete(fileToDelete);
    }
}
```

When the application is restarted `deployment.IsFileGroupDownloaded("GROUPA")` will return false
allowing you to download the FileGroup again at some point in the future.